# Serialization often causes out of memory issue in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, serialization, deserialization

I frequently worked on an out of memory issue, and mostly the OutOfMemoryException is triggered when the code perform serialization or deserialization process.
Most often, this exception caused by the program serialize an object which contains list of another object which with big number of list item and the item has a lot of string properties.

To encounter this issue, I usually reduce the number of property to be serialized. It works in a case where not all properties are needed by the process.

However, there is a case where all properties are needed to be serialized because the properties are used by the next process.
Is there any one that experienced these kind of issue and found a better solution to overcome the issue? For example a solution other than reducing the number of properties to be serialized.

Apologize for my bad english.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What does any of that have to do with MouseEnter on a UserControl?

Comment: Reduce the amount of records instead, sending them in batch.

Comment: @Disaffected1070452 maybe the serialization is done on mouseenter in a custom control :)

Comment: Ah, my bad. Apologize for the incorrect title all. Forgot to change the title of the question. My question is about out of memory issue during serialization process. The previous title about mouse event in user control is wrong, please ignore the previous title.

Thanks for the input @the_lotus , good idea. If I'm not mistaken I have tried this way, but it affects the execution time. The execution become longer than before. Do you have any idea or experience to prevent this solution from affecting the execution time?

Comment: How do you know how long it took if you had an out of memory exception.